# How to use jQuery plugins in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive

I am using AngularJS 1.2 and trying to include a jQuery plugin via an Angular Directive. As an example I have chosen a plugin called [spectrum](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/). I have not included (and do not wish to include) jQuery separately, as AngularJS is said to include jqLite, a smaller version of jQuery.

```
myDirs.directive('spectrumDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.element(element).spectrum(scope.$eval(attrs.spectrumDir));
        }
    };
});
```

However, when i try to load the app, I get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined spectrum.js:1888
>   (anonymous function)

The error stems from the initialization of the plugin:

```
(function (window, $, undefined) {
    …code…
})(window, jQuery);
```

What is the generic solution to including jQuery plugins in AngularJS? Is there any elegant way to achieve this without including the full jQuery library?

> AngularJS comes bundled with a lite implementation of jQuery referred
>   to as jqLite. For Angular’s purposes, this is effectively jQuery,
>   albeit an extremely gutted one. The creators of Angular believe the
>   jqLite API to be sufficient for nearly every application if utilized
>   properly.

Comment: do you have jQuery library included within the page and whether it is included before the plugin

Comment: If the plugin is dependent on jquery, you cannot use it without jquery. AngularJS is not going to do any magic to let the dependency go away :)

Comment: Include jQuery since it is a "jQuery" plugin.

Comment: Ok, but what about jqLite? I know there are a frameworks like Zepto, that are "drop-in replacements" for jQuery. I was hoping I could use jqLite in the same way..?

Comment: You can use jQuery lite - [Here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) is a list of supported jQuery functions. In your case, if you would have made use of only those functions mentioned in the above link, you need not use jQuery - but the plugin seems to require jQuery...

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but try setting the value of jQuery to be equal to `angular.element()`

Answer (score 2):

As "Arun P Johny" said, you must FIRST include the jquery javascript and then your plugin which depends on jQuery

Answer (score 1):

what you want to do is in the plugin either instead of (window, jQuery) export jqLite which is angular.element. So (window, angular.element);

Or even easier before initializing your angular app add 
    window.jQuery = window.$ = angular.element;

As the first line of js in your main script file, if the plugin doesn't use any methods that jqLite doesn't cover you are in luck! Otherwise perhaps include Zepto for a light weight jquery alternative and in the plugin return (window, Zepto);